# Blu-ray player?

Tags: ffmpeg, mplayer, mencoder, blu-ray

I'd like to play bluray discs in my laptop. I found the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD), and there it's explained that one should use mplayer and ffmpeg.

Looking at the repositories, there exist two different mplayer packages (in conflict with each other)

- mplayer
- mplayer2

**Any ideas with of them should I install?**

On the other hand the official documentation seems to be out of date since no mention to Ubuntu after 9.04 is done. **Does the DumpHD package from the repositories work?**

Finally, **Where could the keydb.cfg keys be found?**

I'm open to suggestions, specially of people who had done the job of making it work.

Cheers

Comment: Personally I use VLC Media Player for DVD's and I'm sure it'd work on bluray disks as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VLC to play blu-ray discs but as far as I know it is still impossible to watch  BD+ encrypted discs it will only play aacs encrypted discs for know.

*If some knows a way feel free to add a comment*

So If all you want to watch is aacs discs read on.

1. Install VLC from the Ubuntu Software Center
2. Download the KEYDB.cfg file from http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/
3. Place the KEYDB.cfg file in ~/.config/aacs/
4. Load the blu-ray disc in VLC, check the no menu checkbox or VLC will most likely hang
5. Lastly enjoy your movie

*PS. I have answered your second question in the above steps*

Reference Links:

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967280&highlight=blu-ray